# Create Web Application With Application Pool V2.0

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-application

In SharePoint 2013, Can I Create Web Application With Application Pool V2.0?

If yes, how ?

If not why ?

Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Web Application With Application Pool V2.0.

Minimum software requirements of SharePoint 2013 server is Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.5, which CLR version is V4.0.

Reference:

[Minimum software requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-0#minimum-software-requirements)

[NET Framework versions and dependencies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)